# Application.SendKeys Keys:="{F2}" does not work from Form button subroutine

Tags: excel, vba

This code works fine when called from a macro shortcut key, that is, it puts a pre-selected cell in edit mode.

```
Sub EditActiveCell()
Selection.Activate
Application.SendKeys Keys:="{F2}"
End Sub
```

However, it won't work when called from a subroutine that originates with a UserForm control click.  After the click, the pre-selected cell is "inert" and has to be clicked on in order to enter something into it.  It's like it's selected in VBA, but not in the Excel client.

Also, if I make the routine that is called from the control click as simple as this:

```
Sub UserFormControlClickAction()
ActiveCell.Select
End Sub
```

then the control click subroutine leaves the Selection (a single cell) "inert";  I have to click on it in order to enter into it.

Any help with getting the F2 setting to work consistently from the UserForm control click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, make sure that the userform is modeless. Set the form's `ShowModal` property to False in the VBE.

Place the following code in the userform's code module:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Appactivate Thisworkbook.Name
    EditActiveCell
End Sub

Sub EditActiveCell()
    Selection.Activate
    Application.SendKeys "{F2}", True
End Sub
```

Run the userform and now when you click on the form, the activecell on the worksheet will enter edit mode.

Of course you can use a control's event procedure instead, but I was trying to keep it as simple as possible.